# how to access Microsoft Exchange server from iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-4

In my app i want to access exchange server for events and contacts, how can i achieve this?
Is there any API for this or something else?

Thanks, I greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend strongly this document: [WAP Binary XML Content Format](http://www.w3.org/TR/wbxml/)

If the low level is working, you have to implement the EAS-protocol on top ob wbxml, which is not trivial, because of bugs in the documentation, different behaviour of different protocol versions. It will be a lot of trial an error to examine, why the exchange server does not understand your requests ;-)

for more see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075404/how-do-i-implement-activesync-protocol-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 3):

The only documentation I know is found at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Exchange_ActiveSync_and_iOS4_Devices.

There are some links on the apple [Website](http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/integration/) too, but it's all very marketing-oriented.

Comment: URLs are broken, please double check them.

Comment: @AlaaEldin Apparently, Apple updated their documentation in the last 4 years. The links are now obsolete, but you are welcome to update them if you know where Apple moved the information.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to understand exchange server mechanism:

[Exchange Server Protocol Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Then go through apple documentation about the active sync as Kheldar suggested.

Other then this there is very less documentation is available. Please let us know if you got any good reference.